# How to use an approle with crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my application I use an approle for database connections.
But how do I set this approle on the connections of the reports?

I have no clue of where to start looking - google gives no hints.

Comment: I removed the other tags, since this sounds like a crystal reports question without having anything to do with other tagged things

Comment: Check if this can help you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998.aspx

Comment: I know how to work with Application roles - but what I need to know is how to do this from Crystal reports.

Comment: James: question is for crystal reports from visual studio - so .net code behind a crystal report that does the trick is also on topic. That's why .Net was involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

**Step 1:** Go to the database expert in the report

**Step 2:** Add a command on the same connection as the tables in the report

**Step 3:** Set the following SQL in the command: select  -2147483648 as myField; exec sp_setapprole 'yourAppRoleName','yourAppRolePassword' - you can set the password as a report parameter for security reasons

**Step 4:** Go to the tab 'Links'

**Step 5:** add a link between the field myField and an integer field in the top table of your of your report

**Step 6:** Press 'Link options' and select Inner join, not enforced and type <=

Close all windows of the database expert and the reports runs on the application role.